# Apache Maven 3.3.1 src, Download & Install, Windows 8.1

Tags: java, windows, apache, maven, zip

I'm running Windows 8.1, 64x. Just DL Apache Maven 3.3.1 bin & src.

[Link here:](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Installation)

Extract all on bin, no issues.

Extract all, however, on src, I get the following error:

> "1 Interrupted Action", "Error 0x80010135: Path too long".

[Please see image here:](http://screencast.com/t/guXrueonUYf)

I'd like to better understand the nature of this problem. Suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: To work with Maven 3.3.1 you just need to download bin package not the source package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7-zip ([Download Here](http://www.7-zip.org/)) will solve this. This is one of the known problems.

You can download and unzip your maven download with the 7-zip unzip tool.

Answer (score 1):

this means that the path to your destination folder is too long, for example : C:\firstDirectory\secondDirectory.....\nDirectory\targetDirectory .
And windows has a path limit length, perhaps 256 characters or 128.

So you should for example change the destination and set it as C:\Test\

;)